# Filter envelopes by email docusign

Tags: laravel, docusignapi

I need retrieving all the envelopes that have been signed or sent to an email.

I was trying to do this using the 'accounts/{account_id}/envelopes' endpoint passing the 'search_text' query param. As in the example in documentation https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search

`/v2.1/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes?search_text=Tabs`

But I'm getting always error 400 - INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER. Am I doing this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 4644 is most likely not your account ID. can you check what is your account ID?

Also, add :

```
&from_date=2019-03-04T00:00:00.000Z&to_date=2019-03-07T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: The 4644 is just the ID exemple from the documentation, Im using my account ID. The error was bc I was not passing the 'from_date' e 'to_date', that apparently are mandatory. But in the documentation is not mentioned that they are mandatory..

Comment: We will fix the documentation. thanks for letting me know.